# How to cite the text from an endnote in MLA

Tags: citations, mla

My question is a rather odd one. If I wish to use the text contained in an endnote from the work I'm using in my paper, how would I cite that endnote in MLA format? Would it be regarded as a regular page in the text or is there a more specified system?

Answer (score 1):

I did some quick research on [The Owl](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/09/) and couldn't find any reference to citing an explanatory endnote or footnote in their material.

However, I was able to find someone's unverified explanation [here](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/486994-english-help-how-do-i-cite-a-footnote):

> If you are citing a piece of information contained in a long discursive footnote such as you find in many academic books, just use a standard footnote format in your paper, mention the page number on which the information appears, and after the page number, write the number of the footnote from the book you are citing, e.g., "489, note 37."
>
> For example:
>
> Warren Williams, A Student's Guide to Psychology (Boston: Houghton Mifflin, 1990) 489, note 37.